# How to update a record created on a flow?

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, flow

I am having the following issue with a flow:
The flow creates an account, after a couple of extra screens it needs to update that account, this is a simple version of the flow:
[image: General view of the flow]

The flow saves the id into the variable AccountID.
[image: Id of new record saved]

Further down the road I need to update the account so I have used the Record Update option to update the account:
[image: Update Account]

For some reason the update record is not working, I keep getting the following error message:
**UPSERT --- UPSERT FAILED --- ERRORS : (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) entity type cannot be updated: Client --- for SFDC record with ID : null,**

I did notice that if I dump the ID that was created it is a 18 digit character, so I am not sure if this could be the issue, unfortunately I cant manipulate with a formula the length as in the flow the formula has to return a number.

I notice that it seems necessary to put an extra screen in the flow after a record create to get the id, otherwise the id is null (might be a visual flow bug), ie: if i want to display AccountID on step 2 I get nothing but if i displayed on step 3 (the next screen) it will display the id of the record created

Comment: Does the user have view permission on the new Account? Do you have the Account or wide default to privately?  You may also want a debug screen before the update showing the account Id (and any other helpful info).

Comment: Thats a great idea, I have added a screen to display the id and it actually display the id, so I guess it has to be on the permission setting however this user has it, I am using it in a site, I have adjust the site profile to have all the permissions on Field-Level Security for the account